# How google autocomplete limits works?

Tags: google-maps, google-api

I'm using Google autocomplete on my site.
I read that: Applications that submit requests with an API key are allowed 1 000 requests per 24 hour period.
Today 100 people have submitted the  autocomplete form, how the daily request quota for the API been exceeded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When users are typing a text in the autocomplete element each new symbol in the text input will trigger requests similar to

`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/js/AutocompletionService.GetPredictions?parameters`

When the user selects an address from the list of suggestions this might trigger another request for place details similar to

`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/js/PlaceService.GetPlaceDetails?parameters`

You can see all these requests in the network activity tab of your browser as shown in my screenshot

[image]

Each autocomplete request and each place details request that you see in network activity tab consumes the Places API quota. By default it is 1000 daily requests, but you can enable billing and get 150K daily requests for Places API free of charge:

https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/usage

I hope this helps!